# README file creation from a dtx file

Tags: documentation, dtx

When I run my dtx file, I get a README file with all the information, but there are no (apparent) line feeds in it.  If I look at it with Notepad, everything is strung along with no line breaks at all.

I have tried `\n` and `\\` and `\r\n` in the text between the `readme` guards, but nothing works.

Is this normal? Is there a way to make the README look pretty and readable?  What does CTAN do with this README?

Here is the readme guarded section:

```
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
nucleardata --- Getting info about nuclides into LaTeX documents

E-mail: bn@name.domain

Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later

See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------

This package provides data and commands for blah in \LaTeXe documents. It uses blah requires blah \texttt{tex} file as the argument.

It reads data from two different \texttt{csv} files: \texttt{elementlist.csv} and \texttt{masscsv1.csv} which are blah /latex.

More information
%</readme>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the end-of-line format is unix-style (LF)  while notepad knows only windows format (CR+LF). Use an editor, like Notepad++, which understands Unix EOLN, and can convert between different EOLN formats.